# how to create Jboss-web.xml or jboss-deployment-structure.xml?

Tags: hibernate, jboss, struts

i am new to jboss servers. I am using `Jboss EAP 6`. My project runs fine in Tomcat 7. but it fails to enable in jboss EAP6. I am using struts2, hibernate3.3 and tiles for my project. I think the problem is i did not create the `jboss-web.xml` or `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. Can some one please tell me how to create this file or point me some tutorial about it..
Thanks....

this is the log file data:

```
17:12:22,571 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "XXXX.war"
17:12:26,362 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
17:12:26,440 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.XXXX.war:main" from Service Module Loader
17:12:26,534 INFO  [org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer] (MSC service thread 1-4) Initializing Tiles2 container. . .
17:12:26,581 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/XXXX]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaProperty
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.addSetProperty(Digester.java:2695) [commons-digester-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.initDigesterForTilesDefinitionsSyntax(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:360) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.init(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:299) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.UrlDefinitionsFactory.init(UrlDefinitionsFactory.java:120) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.initializeDefinitionsFactory(BasicTilesContainer.java:406) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.init(BasicTilesContainer.java:130) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.initializeContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:232) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.createTilesContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:198) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.createContainer(TilesContainerFactory.java:163) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener.createContainer(TilesListener.java:90) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener.createContainer(StrutsTilesListener.java:68) [struts2-tiles-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener.contextInitialized(TilesListener.java:57) [tiles-core-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaProperty from [Module "deployment.XXXX.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 20 more

17:12:26,705 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error listenerStart
17:12:26,705 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context [/XXXX] startup failed due to previous errors
17:12:26,721 INFO  [org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess] (MSC service thread 1-4) Removing TilesContext for context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade
17:12:26,737 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./XXXX: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./XXXX: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]

17:12:27,002 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 6) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "XXXX.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./XXXX" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./XXXX: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"XXXX.war\".jboss.security.jacc Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]"]}
17:12:27,033 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011908: Unregister module: Module "deployment.XXXX.war:main" from Service Module Loader
17:12:27,532 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment XXXX.war in 543ms
17:17:30,888 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (HttpManagementService-threads - 7) JBAS014900: Content added at location C:\Program Files\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0\standalone\data\content\11\5867cf3e99641e79fbf2b8bbf36390d31451d2\content
17:17:33,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (HttpManagementService-threads - 7) JBAS014901: Content removed from location C:\Program Files\EAP-6.0.0.GA\jboss-eap-6.0\standalone\data\content\d9\fb56da17a261438f4b0d3387d6207fd857afb8\content
17:17:42,853 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "XXXX.war"
17:17:47,985 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
17:17:48,001 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.XXXX.war:main" from Service Module Loader
17:17:48,063 INFO  [org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing Tiles2 container. . .
17:17:48,329 INFO  [org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Tiles2 container initialization complete.
17:17:48,329 INFO  [org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess] (MSC service thread 1-2) Publishing TilesContext for context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade
17:17:48,422 WARN  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager] (MSC service thread 1-2) Could not create JarEntryRevision!: java.io.FileNotFoundException: vfs:\C:\Windows\System32\content\XXXX.war\WEB-INF\lib\struts2-core-2.1.8.1 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager$JarEntryRevision.build(FileManager.java:297) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager.loadFile(FileManager.java:133) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.FileManager.loadFile(FileManager.java:93) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:887) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:143) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:110) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:168) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]

17:17:48,578 INFO  [com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider] (MSC service thread 1-2) Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
17:17:48,609 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] (MSC service thread 1-2) Dispatcher initialization failed: Unable to load configuration. - bean - vfs:/C:/Windows/System32/content/XXXX.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar/struts-default.xml:47:178
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest class:org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest - bean - vfs:/C:/Windows/System32/content/XXXX.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar/struts-default.xml:47:178
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:221) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:169) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/RequestContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:211) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.RequestContext from [Module "deployment.XXXX.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 20 more

17:17:48,625 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/XXXX]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception starting filter struts2: Unable to load configuration. - bean - vfs:/C:/Windows/System32/content/XXXX.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar/struts-default.xml:47:178
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:431) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:447) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - vfs:/C:/Windows/System32/content/XXXX.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar/struts-default.xml:47:178
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest class:org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest - bean - vfs:/C:/Windows/System32/content/XXXX.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar/struts-default.xml:47:178
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:221) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101) [struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:169) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/RequestContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:211) [xwork-core-2.1.6.jar:]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.RequestContext from [Module "deployment.XXXX.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 20 more

17:17:48,641 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error filterStart
17:17:48,641 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/XXXX] startup failed due to previous errors
17:17:48,641 INFO  [org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess] (MSC service thread 1-2) Removing TilesContext for context: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade
17:17:48,641 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./XXXX: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./XXXX: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]

17:17:48,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 7) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "XXXX.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./XXXX" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./XXXX: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"XXXX.war\".jboss.security.jacc Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]"]}
17:17:48,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011908: Unregister module: Module "deployment.XXXX.war:main" from Service Module Loader
17:17:49,530 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment XXXX.war in 680ms
17:23:46,068 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-/127.0.0.1:8080
17:23:46,068 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-/127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: jboss-web.xml and jboss-deployment-structure.xml are optional in web application. If you are following classical Java EE Web application archive structure, it should work. So it would be best if you copy here the Exception you see when you are trying deploy application.

Comment: i have added the log file.. pls hav a look at it..

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss 6, uri's of resources in the web archive use a custom protocol 'vfs'. 
Struts 2 did not support this before struts 2.3 (neither did spring before spring 3.0.?).

See https://community.jboss.org/thread/164784.

Also, you're missing commons-beanutils.jar in the classpath. It's probably provided by tomcat, but not by jboss. You need to put it in WEB-INF/lib.